# Are there any disadvantages to using column charset different to schema default in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

In my application, I am storing ids in a table as char(16), calculated as hex(uuid_short()) to make it usable with memcached plugin which requires 'key' to be a char or varchar.
**Example value: 57F328CF000003**

If I leave it to default characterset which is utf8, as per [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html) it will use 3x16 bytes becaues utf8 can have max 3 bytes.
However for the possible values in my use case (which is 1-9 digits and A-F), 1 byte ascii character set is sufficient.

I am unsure about whether it is a good idea to change just the column or just the table to use ascii char set? Are there any performance or design implications to using a different charset to the default of schema or the table? Are there any implications to the collation at all? *Currently I use default char set 'utf8' and default collation 'utf8_general_ci'.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible to have different `CHARACTER SETs` (and/or `COLLATIONs`) in different columns in the same table.

The charset for the table is just a *default*; it plays no other role.

In the case of hex, ip addresses, post codes, etc, it is strongly advisable to use `CHARACTER SET ascii` (`latin1` is almost as good).

`CHAR(16)` means there are 16 *characters*, and it is fixed length, so the length is 16 * the longest possible character.  That is 48 bytes for utf8.  32 bytes are wasted.

`VARCHAR(16)` would have a 1-byte length, plus the necessary bytes for up to 16 characters, so 17 in the case of 16 hex characters.

Using ascii is a performance *benefit* because of making the table smaller.  Do it.

`UUIDs` (and MD5s, etc) have a different problem when you have millions of rows -- they are very random, thereby leading to jumping around a lot in the table.  If the table is too big to be cached in RAM, performance can become *terrible*.

When `JOINing` tables on, say, your uuid, the declaration of the uuid in both tables must have the same charset and collation.

Comment: Thank you Rick! Your answer significantly influenced my app's architecture. +1